# how to relate documents in couchdb.when i have two differnet documents

Tags: linker, couchdb, relationship, documents

I am new to couchdb.Now I am working on a couchdb project in my university.My project is football schema,where I have to prepare documents for players and clubs.I have already created individual documents for players and clubs in couchdb.but I dont know how to relate the players documents to the clubs documents.I mean which player belongs to which club...

Comment: {"_id": "33f93ebf66e59994d5359c9e500000e0_Club-info",
   "_rev": "2-b83326aa860d0513fc5de6e7a9af46b8",
   "ClubInformation": [
       {"sl no.": 1,
        "club name": "Eintracht Frankfurt",
        "location": "frankfurt",
        "home stadium": " Waldstadion",
        "Founded": "08.03.1899",
        "club manager": "Rainer Falkenhain"},
       {
           "sl no.": 2,
           "club name": "Sport-Club Freiburg e.V.",
           "location": "freiburg",
           "home stadium": " Mage Solar Stadion",
           "Founded": "30.05.1904",
           "club manager": "Fritz Keller"}]}

Comment: {"_id": "7b66d9e760278e602fe463138d000a19_Hannover",
 "_rev": "4-c4a0726d298f68b9df2b5b53613254d3",
 "PlayerDetails": [
 {
"Position": "Goalkeeper",
"No.": 1,
"PlayerName": "Ron-Robert Zieler",
"Date of birth": "12/2/1989",
"Nationality": "Germany",
"Goals": 0,
"Yellow cards": 1,
 "red cards": 0
       },
       {
           "Position": "Goalkeeper",
           "No.": 14,
           "PlayerName": "Markus Miller",
           "Date of birth": "8/4/1982",
           "Nationality": "Italy",
           "Goals": 0,
           "Yellow cards": 0,
           "red cards": 0
       }]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store a list of doc IDs of players in each *club* document and/or the doc ID of the club of the player in each *player* document.

Then you can use *views* and *lists* to find all players in a team for instance.

Note that it is your responsibility to keep the database consistent (that is to remove the doc ID of a player from its club when you remove the player from the DB for instance).

Comment: thank you so much for your answer...now I got an idea of how to relate these documents.for example, I have added the club-id to each player of the club.then how to use views to display a club and its players?

Comment: Read some examples, try to come up with the best solution you can and if you are still stuck, then post a new question explaining what you tried. Chances are you can answer this one easily by just searching a bit more ;)